# SQL Server 2008 query to find rows containing non-alphanumeric characters in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, non-alphanumeric

I was actually asked this myself a few weeks ago, whereas I know exactly how to do this with a SP or UDF but I was wondering if there was a quick and easy way of doing this without these methods. I'm assuming that there is and I just can't find it.

A point I need to make is that although we know what characters are allowed (a-z, A-Z, 0-9) we *don't want to specify what is not allowed* (#@!$ etc...). Also, we want to pull the rows which **have** the illegal characters so that it can be listed to the user to fix (as we have no control over the input process we can't do anything at that point).

I have looked through SO and Google previously, but was unable to find anything that did what I wanted. I have seen many examples which can tell you if it contains alphanumeric characters, or doesn't, but something that is able to pull out an apostrophe in a sentence I have not found in query form.

Please note also that values can be `null` or `''` (empty) in this `varchar` column.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  This sounds like a regex job

Comment: @OMG Ponies I have updated the subject, it's more of a "I wonder how you could do this" rather than needed for a specific system, but simplicities sake lets just say it's 2008.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Won't this do it?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```

**Setup**

```
use tempdb
create table mytable ( mycol varchar(40) NULL)

insert into mytable VALUES ('abcd')
insert into mytable VALUES ('ABCD')
insert into mytable VALUES ('1234')
insert into mytable VALUES ('efg%^&hji')
insert into mytable VALUES (NULL)
insert into mytable VALUES ('')
insert into mytable VALUES ('apostrophe '' in a sentence') 

SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE mycol LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'

drop table mytable
```

**Results**

```
mycol
----------------------------------------
efg%^&hji
apostrophe ' in a sentence
```

Comment: LIKE doesn't support regexes, only the wildcard.  And we don't know what version currently..

Comment: We don't need a RegEx to solve this problem.  Unless I am missing something.

Comment: Let me rephrase - we don't need full RegEx support. Using the simple pattern matching that LIKE supports (or PATINDEX) should suffice.  We only need to find a single character that is not in the allowed list.

Comment: Could have sworn I did this at some point, I kind of assumed that because '' does not contain any alphanumeric characters that would be returned also. Thanks heaps, that's the answer :)

Comment: For me, my database is not case sensitive, so `COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'` is the same as `COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%[^A-Z0-9]%'` or `COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%[^a-z0-9]%'`

Comment: Work for me. Thanx.

Answer (score 10):

Sql server has very limited Regex support. You can use PATINDEX with  something like this

```
PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z0-9]%',Col)
```

Have a look at [PATINDEX (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx)

and [Pattern Matching in Search Conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489.aspx)

Comment: If you want to use PATINDEX, you need to do something like this:
"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%',mycol) > 1"

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Selecting it in the column list will only show you where the values are.

Comment: This is how I used it to delete rows with non latin caracters in a specific column:
delete  FROM [DefaultConnection].[dbo].[AspNetUsers] where  PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z0-9]%',country) = 0

Answer (score 3):

I found [this](https://thesqlpro.com/2012/10/05/finding-and-removing-hidden-characters-in-your-data-using-dynamic-t-sql/) page with quite a neat solution.  What makes it great is that you get an indication of what the character is and where it is.  Then it gives a super simple way to fix it (which can be combined and built into a piece of driver code to scale up it's application).

```
DECLARE @tablename VARCHAR(1000) ='Schema.Table'
DECLARE @columnname VARCHAR(100)='ColumnName'
DECLARE @counter INT = 0
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

WHILE @counter <=255
BEGIN

SET @sql=

'SELECT TOP 10 '+@columnname+','+CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(3))+' as CharacterSet, CHARINDEX(CHAR('+CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(3))+'),'+@columnname+') as LocationOfChar
FROM '+@tablename+'
WHERE CHARINDEX(CHAR('+CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(3))+'),'+@columnname+') <> 0'

PRINT (@sql)
EXEC (@sql)
SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

and then...

```
UPDATE Schema.Table
SET ColumnName= REPLACE(Columnname,CHAR(13),'')
```

Credit to Ayman El-Ghazali.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COL_NAME LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z $@$.$-$''''$,]%'
```

This works best for me when I'm trying to find any special characters in a string

Comment: What if there are cyrillic, greek, chinese characters?