# Find rows containing symbols in a varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I select rows where a varchar column contains any characters that SQL Server considers a symbol? The symbol can be anywhere in the string.

Is there a SQL Server equivalent of the C# `char.IsSymbol()` function?

Comment: Your usage of the term symbol is very ambiguous

Comment: Basically, If a row has a symbol, I want to pull that row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume for the moment that your definition of "symbol" is any non-alphanumeric character.

**You need to use SQL Server's `LIKE` functionality.**

This will find rows containing non-alphanumerics at the start, end, and anywhere, respectively.

```
Select * from MyTable where MyColumn like '[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'  -- Starts With
```

or

```
Select * from MyTable where MyColumn like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]' -- Ends With
```

or

```
Select * from MyTable where MyColumn like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%' -- contains
```

The performance of the last one is exceptionally bad.

**References**

- [MSDN for Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)
- [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919757/sql-server-2008-query-to-find-rows-containing-non-alphanumeric-chararacters-in-a)

Comment: It will search all rows which has 'car', even there is no any special char(symbol)

Comment: Yes I know `like` but I want to find all the symbols in SQL Server. I want list of symbols that SQL Server considers symbols. I want any and all symbols. List of symbols. I don't know what symbol I will be looking for, but I want all the symbols. If a string has a symbol (any symbol) I want the sql query to pull that row.

Comment: It depends entirely how you define Symbol. Symbol can mean anything. He can work with this

Answer (score 0):

**C#**
U can use `Indexof()` to search for first occurence of  symbol `car` and compare with 0 to check whether it is present at start of column value.

U can use `LastIndexof()` to search for last occurence of symbol `car` and compare with inputstring.Length-3 to check wheteher car is present at end. Here inputstring is the column value.

**SQL Server**
Use `CHARINDEX()` function to find position for occurence of symbol `car`

```
Select * from Table
where CHARINDEX('car',column_name)=1 or CHARINDEX('car',column_name) = LEN(column_name)-3
```

Note : The starting position returned by **CHARINDEX()** is 1-based, not 0-based.

Comment: I want to do this in SQL Server using SQL query, not in C#.

Comment: But you mentioned in question C#...

Comment: You misunderstood the question, he doesn't want to find rows containing `car`, he wants to find rows containing "symbols", by which he seems to mean characters that aren't numbers or letters.